# Show all commits in one branch that aren't from merges

Tags: git, merge, branch, git-log

I have a branch that I've periodically been keeping up to date with merges, which I do like so:

```
git checkout branch
git merge master
// if there are conflicts, fix -> commit the merge
```

Now, when I want to see what commits are on the branch, I get the commits for that branch along with all the commits from master that were merged in. A lot of the things that I've tried

```
git log --first-parent --no-merges
git log branch ^master
git cherry -v master
```

don't give me what I want because the commit hashes of the merged in commits have changed and aren't the same as the corresponding commits on the master branch (I think this is because at some point there were some merge conflicts).

So, I have a few questions.

1. Is there still a way to show only commits not from merges?

   ```
   git log --cherry-pick --oneline --no-merges --right-only master...branch
   ```

   seems to get there kind of, but is still showing in a bunch of merged in commits. Is this likely because I had a bad merge at some point?
2. At the end, if I rebase the branch back into master, will the merged in commits sort of cancel out against the original commits on master and disappear?
3. I would want to be bringing the changes back in on top of the latest stuff, hence the rebase, but I also don't want to somehow duplicate the history of master if all of the commits from the branch that were originally from merges get logged, so would a merge be better in this case?
4. Should I have been using

   ```
   git merge --squash master
   ```

   to keep the branch up to date?

For a bit more about the state of things

```
>>> git log --first-parent --no-merges -n 3
commit 7778493443bd25fee04efad36fef2bc7fe5d3c4a
Author: Author1
Date:   Mon Apr 18 18:37:03 2016 -0400

    Message 1

commit ea83f51be78212867ce2e04a0780ba3b5a7d510c
Author: Me
Date:   Mon Apr 18 15:07:57 2016 -0400

    My commit on branch

commit 4b2e57ca80dccd1f84dd5a6c378ba29768b4db52
Author: Author2
Date:   Mon Apr 18 18:27:36 2016 -0400

    Message 2

>>> git checkout master
>>> git log -n 2
commit a2ac630c8b43f36897bb2c52dc5d49a342aeb2c7
Author: Author1
Date:   Mon Apr 18 18:37:03 2016 -0400

    Message 1

commit 62141ead3da66fc6f5b14a491d3d94d39d111e6a
Author: Author2
Date:   Mon Apr 18 18:27:36 2016 -0400

    Message 2


>>> diff <(git show 4b2e57ca80dccd1f84dd5a6c378ba29768b4db52) <(git show 62141ead3da66fc6f5b14a491d3d94d39d111e6a)
1c1
< commit 4b2e57ca80dccd1f84dd5a6c378ba29768b4db52
---
> commit 62141ead3da66fc6f5b14a491d3d94d39d111e6a
```

Comment: Commit hashes don't change. Merges don't create corresponding commits. `--first-parent --no-merges` should be exactly what you want. Show some actual output.

Comment: jthill you should post your comment as an answer. ;)